# Drupal 7 Create a webform with a map

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I use drupal 7, [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [OpenLayers](https://www.drupal.org/project/openlayers) and I would like to display a form where people can enter some information like name, phone number, etc. and their location.

While it's pretty straightforward to enter textual information do this with [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), I don't know how to add a map to my form.

Could someone tell me if it's possible ?

Thanks

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

Add a map to a page using whatever Map module you use (OpenLayers in your case). Create (or edit) your webform, choose the "Webform" tab then the "Form Settings" tab. Scroll to the bottom and find the "Advanced Settings" Section, expand it and choose the "Available as Block" option.

[image: Block config]

You can then add the Webform as a block on the map page you created using Drupals block interface (`structure/blocks`).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've used the [EntityForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) that seems to be more flexible.
But I'll try your solution as well to see what is the best one ;)

Thanks

Arnaud